# How can i create a new object in a class?(c++)

Tags: c++

Good evening every body~

As the title, How can i create a new object in a class? and i want to give it a number.

How can i do that?

Thank you very much~

Comment: Sorry, but this is a poor question. It's obvious that you're yet to learn the basics of C++, so may I suggest you search for C++ tutorials via Google and start reading. Cheers!

Comment: Completely unclear, can't be answered.

Comment: I suggest a decent book, not shitty online tutorials. Look through http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass {
    int yourNumber;
};
```

or what do you mean?